# action method is being called twice in the controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, view, controllers

The action in my MVC controller is being called twice from my jQuery code. After doing some investigation I found that the link is being triggered by jQuery as well as from the MVC view.

```
$('.treeview-menu li a[name="environments"]').on("click", function () {
    debugger;
    var genericId = $(this).attr('id');
    if (genericId != undefined) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Configuration/Development",
            data: { 'genericId': genericId } ,
            datatype: "application/json",
            success: function (data) { }
        })
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
});
```

```csharp
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Development(DashBoardViewModel model, string genericId)
{            
    ViewBag.EnvironmentType = "Development";
    DeploymentConfiguration_DAL _deploymentDal = new DeploymentConfiguration_DAL();
    model.Configuration = _deploymentDal.FetchDeploymentConfigurationByEnvironmentID(Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToInt32(genericId)));
    if (model.Configuration != null)
    {
        return View("Index", model);
    }
    return View("Index");            
}
```

View where the links are being populated

```
<li>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Deployment Environment</a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Environments)
        {
            <li>
                <a href="@Url.Action(@item.Name,"Configuration")" id="@item.GenericMasterId" name="environments">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>
                    @item.Name
                </a>
            </li>                                                                                                                         
        }                          
    </ul>
</li>
```

The problem that I am facing is when the application runs and after clicking on any of the links that are being dynamically generated. The action method runs the first time and populates my model, but instead of displaying it in my view the action method is being hit again which populates `null` in the model because of which the text boxes are not being bound from the db values.

Please help me in getting this resolved. Is there a way that I can access the `id` value for `href` in my action result without using jQuery?

Comment: Can you show `html` for `.treeview-menu li a[name="environments"]` element?

Comment: It sounds like you have two `a[name="environments"]` elements. Are they nested by any chance?

Comment: added the view that i am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've described in the question, what is happening is:

- the jquery runs fine (but your question code does nothing with the view)
- the link on the href the *redirects* the page to a new view

If you want to get the page and *not redirect*, you can:

- change the `a` to a `button type=button`
- return false from the event handler
- call event.preventDefault() from the event handler
- remove the `href=` (by changing to a button)
- possibly change to a `#` as per other answer, but this is advised against and will have other side affects without one of the above changes as well.

If you want to *redirect* (not stay on the same page), passing in the id, as you say "without using jquery" then change the `@Url.Action` to use the routeValues overload:

```
<a href='@Url.Action(item.Name, "Configuration", new { genericId = item.GenericMasterId })' ... />
```

You can extend the `new { genericId =` to include your other model properties that you need (though id should be enough with some changes to your action).

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace **@Url.Action(@item.Name,"Configuration")** for **href="#"**.

```
<a href="#" id="@item.GenericMasterId" name="environments">
```

This is why you have 2 calls to your controller, 1 in jquery click and another 1 when you click  at link.